# MediaStream JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, видео, mediastream

Как можно отправить поток видео на сервер?

Есть данный фрагмент клиента:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/');


function pageOnLoad() {
    startTranslation();
}


function startTranslation() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        let video = document.querySelector('#captured-video');
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}).then(stream => {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
            postVideoToServer(stream);
        });
    }
}


function postVideoToServer(stream) {
    socket.emit('video', {video: stream});
}
```

И сервера:

```
var io = socketio(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('video', video => {
        console.log(video);
    });
});
```

В итоге video = `{video: {}}`, то есть пустой объект.
Был вариант передать url, но `window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);` выдаёт `TypeError: URL.createObjectURL: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads.`

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно строку:

```js
window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

Заменить на:

```js
window.URL.srcObject = stream;
```

Проблема в том, что `createObjectURL` для `MediaStream` [имеет статус deprecated](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5618491470118912).

Comment: Трансляция идёт. Мне не понятно как на сервер это отправить

Comment: Вы написали `Был вариант передать url, но`, я описал в ответе, как это пофиксить и сделать таки url.

Comment: Если отправить сам объект, то отправится { video: {} }

Comment: Ладно, я напишу window.URL.srcObject = stream;
Дальше как отправить?

Comment: Понял, вам тут скорее всего поможет [RecordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/), вот был подобный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523289/sending-a-mediastream-to-host-server-with-webrtc-after-it-is-captured-by-getuser, но он немного устаревший.

Comment: Я так полагаю данная статья покрывает вашу задачу https://tsh.io/blog/how-to-write-video-chat-app-using-webrtc-and-nodejs/

Comment: Хорошо, я создал объект с помощью `let recordedVideo = new MediaRecorder(stream);`, как теперь отправить на сервер? Какой метод использовать, чтобы отправить записанное видео?

Comment: Я отправлял переменную videoObject `let videoObject = recordedVideo.start();`, но также отправляется пустой объект

Comment: Я думаю вам будет проще спросить тут https://t.me/nodejs_ru. Просто эта проблема вряд лив. Рамках стаковерфлоу решится.

Comment: ответ получен, как байты полученные через MediaRecorder преобразовать в MediaStream?